# /event-id facebook return empty data

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I can catch the profile information of a Facebook account like this:

```
var facebookExample = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngStorage', 'ngCordova'])

facebookExample.controller("ProfileController", function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $location) {

$scope.init = function() {
    if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
        $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", { params: { access_token: $localStorage.accessToken, fields: "id,name,gender,location,website,picture,relationship_status", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
            $scope.profileData = result.data;
        }, function(error) {
            alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
            console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Not signed in");
        $location.path("/login");
    }
};

});
```

Now, I am trying to catch the information of an Facebook event with this:

```
facebookExample.controller("EventController", function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $location) {

$scope.init = function() {
    if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
        $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{event-id}", { params: { access_token: $localStorage.accessToken, fields: "id, name, cover, place, description", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
            $scope.eventData = result.data;
        }, function(error) {
            alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
            console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Not signed in");
        $location.path("/login");
    }
};

});
```

but my  eventData returns empty... I am building an ionic app with cordova and angular. Anyone can help?

Comment: what even is it? a user event or a page event? btw, you can use the javascript sdk with cordova, no need to store the access token and do your own calls...there is also a facebook plugin for cordova afaik.

Comment: its a event created by a page... which facebook plugin?

Comment: for example: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: What kind of access token are you using? Is the event readable by your app/page? Is the event open? Can you provide the ID of the event?